# Regarding Warning: Accessing PropTypes via the main React package is deprecated. Use the prop-types package from npm instead

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-router, jestjs, enzyme

I am running jest with enzyme but I am getting the above warning specifically from react-router dependency in the class I am trying to test. My question is why I am getting this warning as I have already downgraded my react version to 15.1.1.

```
Package.json
 "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.1",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.5",
    "boron": "^0.2.3",
    "browserify": "^13.0.1",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.2.0",
    "debounce": "^1.0.0",
    "envify": "^3.4.0",
    "es6-promise": "^3.2.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.6.3",
    "jquery": "^2.2.4",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "minimist": "^1.2.0",
    "node-fetch": "1.6.3",
    "node-notifier": "^4.6.0",
    "object-assign": "^4.1.0",
    "react": "^15.1.0",
    "react-autosuggest": "^3.8.0",
    "react-dnd": "^2.1.4",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^2.1.2",
    "react-document-title": "^2.0.3",
    "react-dom": "^15.1.0",
    "react-dropdown": "^1.0.4",
    "react-quill": "^0.4.1",
    "react-router": "^2.4.1",
    "react-select": "^1.0.0-beta13",
    "react-select2-wrapper": "^0.6.1",
    "react-tag-input": "^3.0.3",
    "reflux": "0.4.1",
    "request": "^2.81.0",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.0",
    "toastr": "^2.1.0",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0",
    "watchify": "^3.7.0",
    "webpack": "^2.4.1",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-jest": "^6.0.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babelify": "^7.3.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "del": "^2.2.0",
    "enzyme": "^2.1.0",
    "eslint": "^3.19.0",
    "eslint-config-defaults": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.10.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.1",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^15.1.1",
    "jest-cli": "^15.1.1",
    "less": "^2.7.2",
    "less-loader": "^4.0.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.2",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.1.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.29.5",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.10.5",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.3",
    "scss-loader": "0.0.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "yargs": "^7.1.0"
  },
```

The full stack trace of error is:

```
console.error node_modules\fbjs\lib\warning.js:36
    Warning: ReactTestUtils has been moved to react-dom/test-utils. Update references to remove this warning.

 FAIL  web\test\testClass.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Warning: Accessing PropTypes via the main React package is deprecated. Use the prop-types package from npm instead.

      at CustomConsole.Object.<anonymous>.console.error (web\test\jestSetup.js:12:11)
      at printWarning (node_modules\fbjs\lib\warning.js:36:17)
      at warning (node_modules\fbjs\lib\warning.js:60:22)
      at Object.get [as PropTypes] (node_modules\react\lib\React.js:95:49)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules\react-router\lib\InternalPropTypes.js:9:18)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules\react-router\lib\PropTypes.js:12:26)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules\react-router\lib\index.js:15:19)
      at Object.<anonymous> (web\js\components\common\toolBar.jsx:2:20)
      at Object.<anonymous> (web\test\testClass.test.js:5:16)
      at process._tickCallback (internal\process\next_tick.js:103:7)
```

I dont want to upgrade from Router v2 to latest version 4 as I have to do lot of upgradation in my code. Why this error is coming although I am not using latest version of React where this package was moved from 'react' to 'prop-types'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you downgraded your React node module be sure to remove your node_modules directory and reinstall them.  It is most likely one of your other dependencies that upgraded too.  Since you aren't pinning your versions you might end up in the same spot.  I would pin your version or use yarn to generate a yarn.lock file.

Comment: I am putting ^ in front of all my packages. Should I replace it by ~ to make auto-upgradation even more selective.

Answer (score 5):

As of React 15.5.0 PropTypes is no longer apart of the react package and is now its own separate package. So if you want to get rid of the warning you'll need to `npm install prop-types` and then `import PropTypes from 'prop-types'`

https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2017/04/07/react-v15.5.0.html#migrating-from-react.proptypes

Same goes for TestUtils:
https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2017/04/07/react-v15.5.0.html#react-test-utils

Answer (score 1):

React Router has updated the packages to handle the React library changes for 'createClass' and `PropTypes`.

#### Version 2

Doesn't look like they updated this one. Makes sense because version 4 is most current.

#### Version 3

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/releases/tag/v3.0.4

(though you could likely use [3.0.5](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/releases/tag/v3.0.5) safely)